# <pre> within spoilers is not hidden properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, spoilers

When a pre tag is used in spoilers (as the 4-space code block doesn't work), the standard gray pre/code background is not hidden when the spoiler is, but the text color within is set to the spoiler block background. The result is that the text within is actually visible while the spoiler is hidden.

> Hidden
>
> ```
> See what I mean?
> ```
>
> Text

Either the whole pre block should be hidden or the text within should be made the same color as its immediate (gray) background.

Observed on several different sites in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox on OSX Yosemite.

[It appears there is a different bug with the spoiler above on the iOS app.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245144/172958)

Comment: Also, apparently I should have asked it on the iOS app.

Comment: Also, any text within the spoiler, but after the <pre> tag is not rendered within a <p> tag (or any tag for that matter). This makes it difficult to hide on the mobile apps.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to put a <code> tag inside the <pre> tag

```
>! Hidden
>! <pre><code>See what I mean?</code></pre>
>! Text
```

so that you get the following:

> Hidden
>
> ```
> See what I mean?
> ```
>
> Text

Answer (score 1):

I've added some `pre` rules to the spoiler CSS, so this is fixed following the next build.

Comment: You're on a real spoileroller! ;-)

Comment: Despoiler? Went through bugs in the tag...

Comment: haha, so much better. Kudos, even those small things deserve some love. :P