# Spoiler text after a pre tag is not hidden on the iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, mobile-web, spoilers

Viewing [my last question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245142/172958) on the iOS app, I noticed that the line after the pre tag within the spoiler is not hidden at all.

[image: buggy spoiler]

compare with the desktop version

[image: other buggy spoiler]

Comment: The issue is that any text rendered after the <pre> is not rendered inside the <p> tag, so our CSS doesn't hide it.

Comment: This problem appears to affect mobile web too.  The problem, as Arie mentioned, is that the markdown renderer is placing "Text" outside of an element.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I fixed this in January and never updated this question.