# Improper plural on the winter bash site

Tags: bug, status-completed, plurals, winter-bash-2014

At the risk of being attacked by Jeff Atwood with a giant "S,"

[image]

Should be "ask a question."

Comment: Did you at least post this through the app?

Comment: @TimStone I thought about it, but I posted [the last one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245144/172958) through the app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's okay, manual pluralization bugs are different. Fixed.